# Why (and How to fix) when using moment.js and putting the type as a string, it "freezes" the date?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, momentjs

My first problem was that type **Date** did not work with **moment().format("")** unless I changed the type to **String**. But now when it's type string the dates for some reason freeze and don't update when new data is entered in the db.

```
let Blog = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    date: { 
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("MMM, Do YY, HH:mm")
    }
});
```

So what I am trying to do is get the date as I want it formatted and output it to the browser for the client to see when they posted, but the date never updates to the correct time, as if it's frozen.

Here is data from the db, all created a minute from each other. Why and how to fix this, please?

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5daf8c6795e4ce4fe0f8ded8"),
        "date" : "Oct 22nd 19, 16:10",
        "user_blog" : "dummy val",
        "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-22T23:10:31.473Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5daf8c9395e4ce4fe0f8deda"),
        "date" : "Oct 22nd 19, 16:10", // Same 
        "user_blog" : "dummy val 2",
        "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-22T23:11:15.920Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5daf8ce795e4ce4fe0f8dedb"),
        "date" : "Oct 22nd 19, 16:10", // Same
        "user_blog" : "dummy val 3",
        "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-22T23:12:39.117Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

### Edit

Thanks to Nick, I now know why it "freezes". But I then asked above on how to fix this. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Schema, it takes the date from when the schema was created. What you will need to do is pass in the mongoose object to moment, then format it to string:

```
moment(Date.now()).format("MMM, Do YY, HH:mm")
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I put in the object, it gives off "invalid date". It's still not working

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the parens

Comment: Unfortunately, It still doesn't work, It goes back to the first issue I had. :( Is there any other way to get around the schema from copying itself?

Comment: Can you try -

moment(new Date()).format("MMM, Do YY, HH:mm")

Comment: That does not seem to work either. Can it possibly be how I am handling it on the front end? Or is the focus just on how it's handled on the backend?